# IBM Bluemix failed to create API Management

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-api-management

I have a trial version of IBM Bluemix. I tried to create an API Management service instance. First, it shows a message `Just a sec! We're still setting up a few things for you...`. However, after a while, I got the following error message `The service timed out while launching. Please try again.`

Answer (score 0):

Please try our new console
https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/ 
 in provisioning API Management tile.  I was able to provision one without any issue and launch Developer console.

Answer (score 0):

We are not aware of any ongoing issue as you can see on the [Bluemix Status Page](https://status.ng.bluemix.net). I've just tried to create a new instance of [API Management](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/api-management/) using both the [Classic UI](https://console.ng.bluemix.net) and the ["New Experience" UI](https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net). I suggest you to try again, it should work.

If the problem persists I suggest you to open a support request using one of the following methods:

- Use the Support Widget. It is available from the user avatar in the upper right corner of the main Bluemix UI. After opening the support widget panel, select Get Help > Get In Touch , select the type of assistance you need, and then fill out the support form.
- Use the Support Site 'Get Help' form. This form is available on a separate site that is made available for ticket submission when you cannot log into Bluemix and access the Support Widget.  Go to http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport and fill in the support request form.